# Play framework 2: one model approach

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, model, playframework, playframework-2.0

**The problem:**

When programming with play framework I feel that I'm stumbling with same problem than in many times at the past which is **creating several models of the same type** just because I want to add, update or use different data about certain model in different use cases.

Let me explain, lets consider of a example where I have 2 different views: **register** and **login**

I would have following User model:

```
/**
 * Example User class (simple annotations for demo purposes).
 * 
 */
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String email;

    @Required
    public String password;

    @Required
    public String firstName;

    @Required
    public String lastName;

}
```

**In case of registering:** I would have all corresponding fields in register.scala.html : *email, password, firstName, lastName* - because I will need them all when I register, right?

But also I would want to use repeatPassword field to confirm that user has typed password correctly, so I would add this into User model:

```
@Required
@Transient
public String repeatPassword;
```

Ok, then I would extend this model to have repeat password confirmation check in order to correct my "automatic" validations when form is submitted, like this:

```
public String validate() {
if(!password.equals(repeatPassword)) {
    return "Passwords doesn't match.";
}
    return null;
}
}
```

So even now I would have one extra attribute repeatPassword which is not persisted to database but used within registration.

**Problem #1:** Our model starts to go confusing piece by piece.

**In case of login:** I would want to use same model because its a User which is trying to sign in, right? But instead of all the fields I would only need *email, password.*

**Problem #2:** My User model cant be used in login because its already customized to be used within registration - I would need to move repeatPassword and validate() method to separate UserRegistation model, plus duplicate firstName lastName etc. fields or mix using both User and UserRegistration model within registration and to render two different forms to same registration view = confusing.

**Problem #3:** My login page cant use User model because it has annotations in place, if I dont add all the necessary fields like firstName, lastName etc. I will get errors. Again, I would need to create separate UserLogin model just because I want to login to work.? Example below:

```
public class UserLogin {

    @Required
    public String email;

    @Required
    public String password;

    public String validate() {
        if(User.authenticate(email, password) == null) {
            return "Invalid user or password";
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

So very fast, I would have 3 different models just to represent User, one of them is persisted to database and two others is used to validate errors when we are completing login and registration functionality at template side.

So my question is: How on earth I should begin to solve this mess? code complexity is rising very fast :) Should I create separate models.template and models.database packages where template models are only ones within annotations and in case of no errors I start to fill real model before saving or updating its info to database? I need desperately answers from you guys/girls, **Can we make one model approach?** thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start from the end: you don't need to use whole model for `changing password` or `loggin-in` (also you don't need to create separate, 'non-persisted' sub-models), although `Form<YourModel>` is useful while filling large objects, you can just avoid them and rely on common `DynamicForm`.

In such case of course it won't use `constraints` added with annotations to the model's fields but you can validate them manually.

For an example: in registration form you can check if `@Required` fields like `email`, `firstName`, `lastName` exists (tip: also add `MinLength` and `MaxLength` constraints), **but** you should remove `@Required` annotation from `password` field.

Next after checking if the form **hasn't** any errors you can check if `password` and `repeatedPassword` are the same and it they are identical you can also add some individual (advised) `strength check` - most probably it wouldn't be possible with the annotations in the model.

In case of logging form the thing is ever easier: using `DynamicForm` data just try to find existing `User` with given `password` if result is `null` that means, the user doesn't exists or `password` is invalid.

Finally, tip: There is ready-to-use, full-stack [`authentication` and `authorisation` module available for Play 2.0 by Joscha Feth](http://joscha.github.com/play-authenticate/) (and I'm huge advocate of this solution.)

Comment: +1 for for auth module, I tried securesocial before but it would have required too much programming to fit my case(I felt that it was too tied to its own implementation). But what comes to models, I would have liked that we could keep validations inside models using annotations and/or validate() method.. I know that everything or some of them can be also checked at controller side, but then we already would validate in two different places. And I'm not sure if this is better or worse than creating couple sub-models with few attributes :/ but please clarify if I didn't understand you correctly.

Comment: I think that choice between sub-models with annotation and in-controller validation - belongs to you. IMHO when are you gonna to divide your main model into large sub-forms - you can use additional models, if you only to change password it's really faster and cleaner approach to use simple check in the controller.

Comment: yes, I will accept your answer and I will decide to use sub-models and controller validations based on views at hand and for template models maybe different package (not hiding them inside controllers or normal model like an inner class). So yes, maybe bit of IMO thing but as much as we have conventions the more readable code gets between developers.